# Eclipse plugin to automatically generate a template TLD file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

Is there and Eclipse plugin to automatically generate a template TLD file (.tld) when writing custom tags?

Thanks to *nitind* answer :

Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one using the New XML File wizard; the DTD and schema files for tag libraries should be in the built-in catalog.

If you're building .tag files, you won't need one.

Comment: Can you somehow expand that answer? I still can't find `new file XML wizard` and I have the same problem. Step guide would help greatly!

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse XML Editors and Tools installed?

Comment: Yes, I have. Yet I can't find file with `.tld` extension. I opened every single folder inside **file/new/other**. Still, I am not able to generate anything similar to picture shown in question's description. Can you tell me where after **other** do you go?

Comment: There's no dedicated wizard for `.tld`s, they're just created using the normal New XML File wizard and the right DTD or schema file.